# Create repeating detailed layout programmatically while using do in background

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, repeat

I've been around and I've seen repeating layout examples. I'v even tried a few but to no avail. Most don't provide a real representation of what I am trying to accomplish below. I did encounter one which seemed to work but caused a error because I was trying to use .add to the parent layout and android didn't like it. I need the layout to be dynamic so I can use different details on each item that is being repeated without overwriting the previous ones as well.

Below is the XML for the repeating layout, it is in a different layout then the activity, I'm not sold on that and if there is a better way I'd like to know. I'm sure my structure is a little overloaded but I'm not concerned about that at this time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shop_item_banner"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shop_back_missing_image" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.83"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="TextView" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="TextView" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="TextView" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/shop_divider_section" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shop_big_button"
                        android:text="BUY"
                        android:typeface="normal" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code which updates the structure of the page. It is updating a LinearLayout which lives inside a ScrollView so users can scroll items. I started to shrink my code so I could debug my issue. So far I've gotten down just to a while loop to print the layout three times. Once works fine but after I let it run more than once the thing fails and the app force closes. I get a warning that I am no longer able to add items to the selected layout.

```
    public class LayoutStream extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    String data = null;
    LinearLayout layoutList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ScrollItem);

    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {         
        return data;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String tpresult){
        int run = 5;
        View storeitems = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shop_item, null);
        while (run > 3){

            layoutList.addView(storeitems);
            run--;
        }   
    }
}
```

Any assistance is appreciated, this has been a big hurdle and I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out why this is performing this way.

The error code is before. The error is when trying to add a element during the postexecute()

03-21 21:27:44.245: W/dalvikvm(30172): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1970)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1822)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1802)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at com.example.myapp.app.myshop$TokenStream.onPostExecute(myshop.java:188)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at com.example.myapp.app.myshop$TokenStream.onPostExecute(myshop.java:1)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:885)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
03-21 21:27:44.255: E/AndroidRuntime(30172):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?Post error log

Comment: I'm going to when I get out of work this afternoon. I didn't have time to get the error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer to my problem. I was close to the solution when I first started with it. This allows me to also target each item being created to update it as they are created.

```
public class LayoutStream extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    String data = null;
    LinearLayout layoutList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ScrollItem);

    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {         
        return data;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String tpresult){
        int run = 5;
        LinearLayout layoutList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ScrollItem);
        LayoutInflater IInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        while (run >= 1){

            View storeitems = IInflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_item, null);
            layoutList.addView(storeitems, 0);
            run--;
        }   
    }
}
```